# Remove blank page between chapters for scrbook or scrreprt

Tags: koma-script, scrbook, blank-page, scrreprt

I'm using [this](https://www.matthiaspospiech.de/latex/templates/thesis/) latex template of Matthias Pospiech (version 3.2.5) for my thesis. I have problem with avoiding blank page between chapters. I have tried the command `\documentclass[openany]{scrreprt}` and `\documentclass[openany]{scrbook}`. I also removed the `cleardoublepage=empty` in `style.tex` but the new chapter keeps on beginning at odd number page. I'm not sure how to get around this and the project has so many `.tex` files too. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: May I suggest not to use that template? `;-)` But you could try `\KOMAoptions{open=any}` before `\begin{document}` (after all the template's `\input`).

Comment: Hi thanks, your solution works! May i ask why you suggest not to use the template?

Comment: After speding quite a bit of time, twitching the project code, I would feel it all goes to waste if i decide not to use the template. Also its design sastisfies me the most

Comment: That's just my personal taste, don't take me too seriously. The preamble of my larger works (PhD thesis, Habilitation, a book) is some 40 lines long, loads just a couple of packages, and makes some minor redefinitions. I have a package with my math macros. That template has a preamble split in over a dozen files, loading lots of stuff, hides lots of `\KOMAoptions` instructions which, as you have noticed, can have unforeseen effects. It tries to cope with everything and is quite hard to entangle. But again: opinion based on personal taste.

Comment: yes, I totally get what you mean! It takes so long to load the template in overleaf. Unfortunately, i don't have much time focusing on the typesetting and i just look for some quick to-go template with a twitch every here and there. Do you know a better (more trimmed down) version of this template or any of similar style? I looked around in overleaf gallery but couldnt find something to my taste

Comment: also a less urgent problem but it irks me. would be really great if you can take a look. If not no problem too!

Comment: I haven't actually compiled anything with the template, I just looked at the code, so I don't know exactly how the output looks like. I might give it a look but for me it's evening and time to eat `:-)`

Comment: ```\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \large
  \sffamily 
  {\def\arraystretch{1.2}
      \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}p{3.8 cm}p{5.3 cm}}
         Gutachter& \printNameOfSupervisor\\
         Betreuer& \printAdditionalExaminers
      \end{tabular}
  }
\end{table}```                                                                                                                     i got an error for this table when i added it to the `0-title.tex`. It said 'Undefined control sequence'.

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
\KOMAoptions{twoside=false}
```

before `\begin{document}`. Alternatively, in the file `preamble/style.tex`, uncomment line 404

```
%twoside=false, % single side layout
```

Comment: ```                                                                                                               
\begin{table}[h]
  \centering
  \large
  \sffamily
  {\def\arraystretch{1.2}
     \begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}p{3.8 cm}p{5.3 cm}} 
         Gutachter &\printNameOfSupervisor \\
         Betreuer & \printAdditionalExaminers
  }
\end{table}
```
I also have problem with this can you take a look? I got an error for this table when i added it within the `titlepage` environment to the `0-title.tex`.

Comment: Leave away `\begin{table}[h]...\end{table}`, add `\end{tabular}`. Moreover, it's better to replace `\centering` by `\begin{center}...\end{center}`, otherwise too much may get centered. Finally, there seems to be a spurious `}` after `\printAdditionalExaminers`